# How to store day+time slots in sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have application where owners of shops can add their shops. For each shop I have to store an information when the shop is open. For example

- Monday 8:00 - 20:00
- Tuesday 9:30 - 22:00
- Sunday 11:00 - 18:00

I have a table with shops (id, name, address, e-mail, etc). What is a correct way to store information about these day+time slots when each shop is open in sql database?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL

Comment: I would recommend creating a new table for `StoreHours` with a foreign key for `ShopID` then having a row for each store that has 7 columns (One for each day: Sunday - Saturday). You could also do this by adding 7 columns to your `Stores` table if you didn't want to create a new table. Another tip is to store your DAY as an int representing the day of the week (ex: Sunday - 1, Saturday - 7 like DATEPART in sql server). This would save space in the long run rather than spelling the day out.

Comment: Do you need to handle holiday hours or hours that vary from the "standard"  Two tables one with storeID (PK), dayofweek (PK), open time, close time.  a second table similar but instead of dayofweek we have date.  Hours are displayed based on standard but those from second table show up if the date is within x days (7,14) from current date.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one correct way, there are several methods with various advantages and disadvantages.

If you're going to use the data to see if a shop is currently open, I think the most easily used is to define a second table with one day's worth of hours for one store per row

```
CREATE TABLE StoreHours(
    HourID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    StoreID  int NOT NULL,
    DayOfHours int NOT NULL, 
    --Could be char(2) if you wanted to store day as Su, M, Tu, ...
    --but storing as an integer is useful with other queries
    Opens time(0) NOT NULL,
    Closes time(0) NOT NULL,
    --And maybe LastUpdated datetime(0) if you cared
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StoreHours] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( HourID ASC )
)
```

Queries can use the date functions (like DatePart) to determine the day of week, which can then be used, along with StoreID, to look up the day's hours.

For example, to find open gas stations, a query might look like this (obviously more useful if you also have geolocation data ...)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Store as S INNER JOIN StoreHours as H on S.StoreID = H.StoreID
WHERE S.TypeOfStore = 'Gas Station' 
    AND H.DayOfHours = DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE())
    AND CONVERT(TIME(0), GETDATE()) < H.Closes
    AND CONVERT(TIME(0), GETDATE()) > H.Opens
```

On the other hand, if you're just displaying them (like on a web site) without making any comparisons, then storing them as a text string would save you work. You could still do the secondary table and one row per day, or you could use one row per store with each day's hours in a dedicated column. That's really hard to use in queries, but very easy to just display.